# A wired occlusion culling phenomenon in unity3d, could you help me fix it?

Tags: game-engine, unity-game-engine, gear-vr, occlusion-culling

I found a wire occlusion culling problem. Something in my view, but they acre culled. And give a back a black hole. They look like:

[image: occlusion 1]
[image: occlusion 2]

- In picture1, There is a floor mesh, but it is gone, when I open the occlusion culling, but when I shutdown it, it showed as normal.
- In picture2, the whole ground is culled, also it is in the view.

Do you know how to fix it? It nearlly made me crazy.

Comment: Are the face-normals pointing in the right direction and is your triangle winding in the right order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to fix this problem.

It is

- Decreasing the value of *smallest hole* in occlusion culling's baking setting

There is a Chinese post, [Unity4.3遮挡剔除：故障排除](http://blog.csdn.net/huang9012/article/details/40304387) talking about this problem.